# Cypher query - Only match on subset of nodes connected to one node

Tags: neo4j, cypher

How do I build an efficient cypher query to pull only 'City' and 'Age' connected to the 'Group'-labeled node? Thanks in advance

[image]

I have tried this query so far:

```
MATCH(a:Group)-[r]-(b) WHERE b:City OR b:Age RETURN a, b
```

This query gets me half way there. It returns the correct data but, in the table format the data is wrong. I want to include cases where there's additional Group node that is connected to City,Age,Name, and Race

The query should return in this format where each row is a distinct group:

```
Group1, City, Age
Group2, City, Age
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @TomažBratanič added a query of what I've done so far

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does it not work if you specify the relations directly in cypher? I get the expected result from your question:

```
MATCH (g:Group)-->(c:City), (g:Group)-->(a:Age)
RETURN a, c, g
```

or even

```
MATCH (a:Age)<--(g:Group)-->(c:City)
RETURN a, c, g
```

Sample data:

```
CREATE (g1:Group{name:"Group1"}),
  (g2:Group{name:"Group2"}),
  (a:Age{name:"42"}),
  (c:City{name:"Springfield"}),
  (a)<-[:R]-(g1)-[:R]->(c),
  (a)<-[:R]-(g2)-[:R]->(c)
```

Comment: Yes, thank you those queries seem to work as well.

Comment: After some testing, this query works too. Not sure the performance implications though:

MATCH (a:Group)-[r]-(b)
WHERE b:City OR b:Age
RETURN DISTINCT a, collect(DISTINCT b) AS sets

Comment: @sprint_6 You can always prepend [`EXPLAIN` or `PROFILE`](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/query-tuning/#how-do-i-profile-a-query) to your query to get the execution plan or a detailed analysis, respectively

Answer (score 0):

You could try :

```
MATCH (a:Group)-->(b:City), (a)-->(c:Age)  RETURN a,b,c
```